# Differentiation of vector-valued function and linear transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **1.** Let $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^1\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be vector-valued function with components $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n$. Then $$\mathbf{f}'=(f^{'}_1,f^{'}_2,\dots, f^{'}_n)$$

It's definition of differentiation of vector-valued function from Rudin's PMA (Topic 5.16).

> **2.** But in Chapter 9 he defines the derivative of function $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ as linear transformation $A\in L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ such that $$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x})=A\mathbf{h}+\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{h}),$$ where $\dfrac{|\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{h})|}{|\mathbf{h}|}\to 0$ as $\mathbf{h}\to \mathbf{0}$.

I guess that **1)** is a particular case of **2)**. Am I right?

**Proof:** Let $\mathbf{f}:\:\mathbb{R}^1\to \mathbb{R}^m$ is differentiable at point $x\in \mathbb{R}^1$ then $\mathbf{f}(x+h)-\mathbf{f}(x)=Ah+\mathbf{r}(h),$ where $\dfrac{\mathbf{r}(h)}{h}\to 0$. Writing it in coordinate form we get for any $j=\overline{1,n}$ $$f_j(x+h)-f_j(x)=A_jh+r_j(h) \qquad  (*)$$ where $A_jh$ and $r_j(h)$ are components of $Ah$ and $\mathbf{r}(h)$, respectively. Since $\dfrac{\mathbf{r}(h)}{h}\to 0$ then $\dfrac{r_j(h)}{h}\to 0$ also. But dividing $(*)$ to $h$ we get: $\frac{f_j(x+h)-f_j(x)}{h}=\frac{A_jh}{h}+\frac{r_j(h)}{h}$.

Is $\dfrac{A_jh}{h}=A_j$? I am doubt in this because $A_jh$ is $j$th component of $Ah$ and does this dividing is legal? Here's my thought: It's easy to see that each $A_j$ is also linear operator $L(\mathbb{R}^1)$ but any such linear operator has form $\alpha_j \cdot h$ for some real number $\alpha_j$. Then $\alpha_j=f^{'}_j(x)$. Am I right?

Then we get that $A_j=f^{'}_j(x)$ and $A=\mathbf{f}'(x)$. Also $Ah=(A_1h, \dots, A_nh)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathbf{f}'(x)h=(f^{'}_1(x)h,\dots, f^{'}_n(x)h)$. How to conclude that $f'(x)=(f^{'}_1(x),\dots, f^{'}_n(x))$. This moment little bit confuses me.

Can anyone help please? I would be greatly appreciate any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's apply the principle 2. with ${\bf h}:=t{\bf e}_k$, where ${\bf e}_k$ is a standard basis vector in ${\mathbb R}^n$. Then
$${\bf f}({\bf x}+t{\bf e}_k)-{\bf f}({\bf x})=t\>A{\bf e}_k +{\bf r}(t{\bf e}_k)\ .\tag{1}$$
Here $A{\bf e}_k=:{\bf a}$ is a vector, namely the $k^{\rm th}$ column vector of the matrix $\bigl[A\bigr]$. Dividing $(1)$ by $t\ne0$ we obtain
$${{\bf f}({\bf x}+t{\bf e}_k)-{\bf f}({\bf x})\over t}={\bf a}+{{\bf r}(t{\bf e}_k)\over t}\to{\bf a}\qquad(t\to0)\ .\tag{2}$$
In the case $n=1$ there is just one ${\bf e}_k$, and we are allowed  to write ${\bf x}=:x$, $t{\bf e}_1=:t$. Therefore $(2)$ can be rewritten as
$$\lim_{t\to 0}{{\bf f}(x+t)-{\bf f}(x)\over t}={\bf a}\ .$$
This shows ${\bf f}'(x)={\bf a}$ as an $m$-dimensional limit, which by standard rules about such limits is equivalent with $$f_i'(x)=a_i\qquad (1\leq i\leq m)\ .\tag{3}$$
This argument can be reversed: If we are in the case $n=1$ then from $(3)$ we can conclude that $(1)$, resp., the principle 2., holds.